# Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight not found

Tags: android, xml, material-design, material-components-android

In my build.gradle, I included the material design library(version 1.1.0) but in `styles.xml`, when I try to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`, it says `cannot resolve symbol`. Wasn't the DayNight theme already implemented in material design library 1.1.0? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">` also with the version **1.1.0**.

Comment: For some reason Android studio does not allow a version 1.1.0 at this moment--I had to use an alpha/beta version instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

https://m3.material.io/

https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/getting-started

According to the `Material design 3` latest version is `1.5.0`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I upvoted it already. Thank you for the answer. I tried it and it worked

Comment: You can use the same theme also with the version 1.1.0